# Should qgis-python-api be a synonym of pyqgis?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've just proposed [qgis-python-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-python-api) as a synonym of [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis).

[qgis-python-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-python-api) has been only used in 4 questions and they clearly (from the questions themselves) refer to [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis). Check by yourselves:

- [Editing of vector layer programmatically with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78596/editing-of-vector-layer-programmatically-with-qgis)
- [Error 14: Could not open CRS database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93637/error-14-could-not-open-crs-database)
- [What is the QGIS 2.2 print layout map extent CRS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101950/what-is-the-qgis-2-2-print-layout-map-extent-crs)
- [PyQgis api returns wrong layer CRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102037/pyqgis-api-returns-wrong-layer-crs)

As [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) is widely used in GIS.SE and in QGIS documentation itself, [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) would be the master tag.

This is the direct link to the proposal: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/pyqgis/synonyms

Comment: +1 This sounds like a synonym to me too - and I suggest that we should go one step further and perform a merge of the two tags as [tag:pyqgis] which still leaves [tag:qgis-python-api] as a synonym but also retags those four questions at the same time.

Comment: Right, you know better the tools moderators have at their disposal. I could also edit the tags manually, but your solution is optimal.

Comment: @PolyGeo It's not clear for me how this process ends up with some answer. Should I invite people to vote on the proposal? Do people have to wait for a period of time before starting to vote?

Comment: The closest thing we have to a formal procedure on this is documented as [Guidelines for proposing tag synonyms](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/guidelines-for-proposing-tag-synonyms).  However, unless we see some opposing opinions, I am happy to go ahead and implement it after about a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a synonym to me too.

I suggest that we should go one step further and perform a merge of the two tags as [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) which still leaves [qgis-python-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-python-api) as a synonym but also retags those four questions at the same time.

Comment: (This must be a déjà vu). @PolyGeo Do you know where I can find documentation about this merging process? I want to make sure it will not affect my Synonymizer badge :D.

Comment: It's described at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119377.  I doubt that merge vs synonym affects badges but I always treat badges as a bonus so I don't plan to investigate that.

Comment: @gcarrillo A merge has the option of creating a synonym as well. Not sure what happens if already suggested, and can't find anything in a quick Meta search. It might be worth pointing out that not only is there an answer score threshold to *suggest* a synonym, but you also have to meet it to *vote* on those suggestions. There are 20 top users, the lowest of whom has a 9 score. That suggests that only 20-25 people on the entire site *could* vote to get you your badge. That's why we just suggest them here and let the mods do it, and don't pay attention to the badge and who gets creation credit.

Comment: Within a few days, assuming no dissent on the "vote", I (or one of the other mods), will most likely hit the "approve" button on this synonym, followed by the "merge" button.  In the meantime I encourage anyone who wants this synonym, and has the privilege, to vote at http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/pyqgis/synonyms because I would like to see that mechanism work (perhaps for the first time).

Comment: Thank you both for your clarifications. I'm still learning how different aspect of GIS.SE work in practice.